# How to create controls at runtime?

Tags: mfc, controls, runtime

How to create dynamic MFC controls and handle message maps of the controls at runtime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It really depends on which controls do you want to create, especially if you want to know which flags should you set. In general it goes down to this:

Normally a CWnd-derived control is created using `Create` or `CreateEx`. For a CButton, for instance:

```
CButton button;
button.Create("Button text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_PUSHBUTTON | DT_CENTER, CRect(5, 5, 55, 19), this, nID);
```

where the `CRect` specifies the button position, `this` is a pointer to the parent window, and `nID` is the control ID.

If the control doesn't come out as expected, it's probably because some flags are missing. I suggest you draw a sample control in design mode, check out the code for that control in the RC file, and copy the flags to the `Create` caller.

As for the message maps, they are normally routed to the parent window. The `nID` value you used in `Create` is important here, because it will be the number that identifies the control in the message map. If you have a fixed number of controls, you can hard-code the `nID` numbers for your controls (starting at 10000, for instance); if not, you'll have to provide a way for the parent window to identify them. Then you just add the message map entries.

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(10000, OnBnClicked)
ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, 10010, 10020, OnBtnsClicked)
```

You can use the `ON_CONTROL_RANGE` message map to map a range of IDs to the same function.